# Vandermonde matrix unique solution to polynomial equation

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, inverse

[image]

I want to verify if I am thinking of parts b) and c) correctly.

To find its kernel, we must find the nullspace of the matrix equation

$
\begin{bmatrix}
5^5 & 5^4 & 5^3 & 5^2 & 5 & 1 \\
4^5 & 4^4 & 4^3 & 4^2 & 4 & 1 \\
3^5 & 3^4 & 3^3 & 3^2 & 3 & 1 \\
2^5 & 2^4 & 2^3 & 2^2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_5 \\
a_4 \\
a_3 \\
a_2 \\
a_1 \\
a_1 
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\
0 \\ 
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Due to the fact that this is a vandermonde matrix with distinct geometric ratios for its rows, this matrix has full rank and thus has a trivial nullspace I think?

Then, to show part c that there is a unique polynomial such that $f(j) = a_j$, can we then just say that 
$
\begin{bmatrix}
5^5 & 5^4 & 5^3 & 5^2 & 5 & 1 \\
4^5 & 4^4 & 4^3 & 4^2 & 4 & 1 \\
3^5 & 3^4 & 3^3 & 3^2 & 3 & 1 \\
2^5 & 2^4 & 2^3 & 2^2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_5 \\
a_4 \\
a_3 \\
a_2 \\
a_1 \\
a_1 
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_5 \\
a_4 \\ 
a_3 \\
a_2 \\
a_1 \\
a_0 \\
\end{bmatrix} $

has a unique solution due to nontrivial nullspace?

Comment: It seems that replacing "nontrivial nullspace" by "trivial nullspace" in the last line above, something you derive just before,  gives that your system has exactly one solution. This is what you are after. It is not necessary to calculate the solution explicitly by inverting the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are right saying that this is a Vandermonde matrix and hence is invertible, however, this exercise is basically how one proves this fact. You can use the formula to compute such a determinant (which does not use this exercise), but I guess this is not the spirit of the assignment.

How about saying instead that $T$ is invertible, since if $f\in V$ is such that $T(f)=0$, then $f$ has $6>5$ distinct roots, so that $f=0$.

For the rest of the exercise, your solution is fine.

Comment: Ah thank you, algebraic closed-ness of $\mathbb{C}$ is so much nicer than inverting the matrix.

Comment: In fact, it will work in any field, what I used is the fact that in a field a polynomial cannot have more roots than its degree. Why do you think algebraic closedness of $\mathbb{C}$ is relevant to the discussion?

Comment: That is true. However in this question I was referring to the fact that a degree 5 polynomial will have  exactly 5 roots over C for sure, so it will have $\leq$ 5 roots over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Oh sure, that is certainly a way to see it, a bit overkill though! :)